# How to prevent Chrome from flickering when using width transitions?

Tags: css, google-chrome, width, css-transitions, progress

I have a website that is written from right to left, and I would like to create a custom progress bar (using nested `<div>` elements, rather than the `<progress>` element).

My basic HTML file looks like this (I have included the CSS and the JavaScript in the same file):

```html
<!doctype html>
<html dir="rtl">
<head>
  <title>Flickering issue</title>
  <style>

    body {
      margin: 20px;
      direction: rtl;
    }

    #container {
      width: 50%;
      height: 13px;
      border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
      background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .05);
    }

    #progress {
      width: 0;
      height: 100%;
      transition: width 800ms;
      background: linear-gradient(to left, rgb(0, 160, 0), rgb(0, 200, 0), rgb(0, 235, 0));
    }

  </style>
</head>
<body>

  <div id="container">
    <div id="progress"></div>
  </div>

  <script>

      var progress = document.getElementById("progress"),
          curWidth = 0,
          interval = setInterval(updateWidth, 1500);

      function updateWidth() {
        progress.style.width = (curWidth += 4) + "%";
        if (curWidth >= 100) {
          clearInterval(interval);
        }
      }

  </script>

</body>
</html>
```

In Chrome, the right edge of the progress bar flickers whenever the width is updated, and it's really ugly and annoying. This issue does not happen in Firefox.

I've looked for similar issues online, and noticed this is a common problem in Chrome. However, none of the solutions I've found helped solve my issue.

I've tried the following CSS rules:

```
backface-visibility: hidden !important;

transform: translateZ(0) scale(1,1) !important;

transform-style: preserve-3d !important;
```

, but nothing changes...

Thanks in advance for any help.